# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when running Neo4j Graph algo Louvain

Tags: algorithm, neo4j, cypher

When executing the [Louvain algorithm](https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-algorithms/current/algorithms/louvain/) from the neo4j-graph-algorithms, I run into the following error.

> Neo.ClientError.Procedure.ProcedureCallFailed: Failed to invoke procedure `algo.louvain.stream`: Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2409421

I must also point out that the value right after the exception changes slightly (+/- 1000) from one execution to another.
Moreover, setting up the algorithm's parameter '**graph**' to '*huge*' also resulted in the same error.
Here is the Cypher query I am using,

```
CALL algo.louvain.stream('${Label}', '${rel}', {graph : 'huge', concurrency : 4}) YIELD nodeId, community
```

Below some characteristics of the environment:

- neo4j-community-3.4.4
- graph-algorithms-algo-3.4.4.0
- apoc-3.4.0.1-all
- dbms.memory.heap.initial_size=512m
- dbms.memory.heap.max_size=8G

Graph characteristics:
 - 2.4M nodes
 - 10M edges

Thank you in advance for any pointers on how to solve this issue.

kind regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try the latest version of the Graph Algorithms library (3.4.8.0). We made some fixes to the Louvain algorithm and it's possible the problem you're seeing is fixed by those.

Cheers, Mark

Comment: The latest version indeed solves the issue. 
Many thanks for your response.
Cheers,